# Unable to click on link through selenium webdriver present under <td> tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the link present under the TD tag of HTML element.
Please find the below HTML file and Link name. Please help me to figure out the problem.

I have to click on the Metric link highlighted in the bold.

```
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 hand-cursor" tabindex="0" style="width: 625px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1" unselectable="on">**Metric**</div>
</td>

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Metric")).click();
```

Thanks :-
Nitish Gaurav

Comment: Please share your selenium code.

Comment: <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 hand-cursor" tabindex="0" style="width: 625px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1" unselectable="on">**Metric**</div>
</td>

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Metric")).click();

Comment: you can use linktext for links only I think..this is div and text has no link. Please try with css selector or xpath to select element.

Answer (score 0):

`By.linkText()` only works for anchor tags.

You need to use other locators to perform your actions. You can use below method:

`By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'**Metric**')]")`

Comment: Hi Paras, I have used XPATH as well but I am unable to click on the link. Please suggest any other ways.

Comment: can you give your exact html code that you are checking?

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath to click on the element, like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-cell-inner') and contains(text(),'Metric')]")).click();
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Metric')]")).click();
```